# Dealocating 2d arrays pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

What am I doing wrong? I allocated using new but when i try to delete[] it gives me an error.

mycode:

```
int** ma;
int n;
int m;
m = nr_col_lin;
n = nr_col_lin;

ma = new int*[m];
for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    ma[i] = new int[n];

for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        ma[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

and the dealocation:

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
     delete[] ma[i];

delete [] ma;
```

EDIT:

I found the problem... it wasn't in the code... I was deleting something I didn't allocate.

Comment: Do you honestly think that "it gives me an error" is a statement that is helpful to anyone, and is it really the best you can come up with?

Answer (score 3):

There is *absolutely nothing* wrong in your code. It is perfect. The probem must be somewhere else, assuming `nr_col_lin` is initialized with some valid value, i.e make sure it is not `0` or negative. If it is `size_t` or some unsigned integral value, then make sure `m` and `n` are  greater than 0.

Comment: ok i did that but it still gives me an error. if i had 2 pointers ma1 and ma2, and i said ma1 = ma2, its wrong to use delete[]  ma1?

Comment: 'Correct' yes, 'perfect'... well, count the numbers of asterisks and `delete`s, multiply by awful and sprinkle with shavings of terrible.

Comment: @Dementor: No it is not.But,It is wrong to use `ma2` after `delete[] ma1`. Most likely, You are dereferencing a Dangling pointer.

Comment: *absolutely nothing wrong* needs a edit, this code is just wrong..way too wrong even if it is semantically correct & works fine this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @Nawaz: If you *really* can't see anything wrong(I already said it is semantically correct) with this code, I am going to pass on the argument regarding good, bad and ugly coding practices.Cheers.

Comment: @Als: That doesn't make sense here, in this context, and in the context where I said what I said. Also, if using pointers is wrong, *way too wrong*, then Standard would have said it itself. **It is perfect as per the Standard**.